# OLAP ParallelPeriod Calculated member dosen't work for some periods

Tags: mdx, olap

I have a strange problem, that affects only when processing a Calculated Member in OLAP cube, but not when writing MDX query on said cube.

ParallelPeriod function returns correct values when offsetting by 1 year, or 2 half-years, but not on 1 half-year (same for 12 and 6 months)

I want to get data from the previous half-year next to the current measure to do some math with it.

The following MDX query works as expected:

```
With Member [LastPeriodValue] As
([Measures].[PP E VERT],
ParallelPeriod(
[DIM_TIME].[Half Year].[Half Year]
,1
,[DIM_TIME].[Half Year].CurrentMember
        ))
Select
NONEMPTY ({
[DIM_TIME].[Half Year].children
}) on 0
, { [Measures].[PP E VERT], [Measures].[LastPeriodValue] } on 1
from  [Cube];
```

However, when I create a calculated member the result is filled with (null) values.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].IeprVertibaStub
 AS (
    [Measures].[PP E VERT],
    ParallelPeriod(
        [DIM_TIME].[Half Year].[Half Year]
        ,1
        ,[DIM_TIME].[Half Year].CurrentMember
    )
), 
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [PP E VERT] }, 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

However if I change the ParallelPeriod function value in calculated member from 1 half-year to 2 half-years everything works as expected.

I tried the same with LAG function and the results are of similar nature. Works on year period, but not on half-year period.

Does anyone have any ideas where to dig for the problem?

Comment: Not using the same time dimension? [DIM_TIME] VS [STS_OLAP_KMS_DIM_LAIKS]

Comment: I'm guessing that you need to ensure that all attribute hierarchies need to be in the correct order for this to work.

Comment: Sorry @mxix it was the same dimension, forgot to rename the last two for readability.. Edited now.